# IF function formula logic

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logic

My code is this:

```
=IF(AND(C53=D53,C53="STI",D53="STI"),"No OR, Straight to IM",IF(AND(C53=D53,ISBLANK(C53),ISBLANK(D53)),"No Date Input",IF(AND(C53 = "Still Pending",D53>=DATEVALUE("1/1/2013")),"Error, Check Again",IF(AND(C53>=DATEVALUE("1/1/2013"),D53 = "Still Pending"),TODAY()-C53,D53-C53))))
```

When C53 is a date (ex:1/8/2016), and D53 is "Still pending", I believe it should return TODAY()-C53. Instead it returns D53-C53.

Can anyone help me with this logic?

Comment: Is there any sample data to go along with this?

Comment: If you described the reasoning for your logic in words, we could help understand what your formula is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your formula wasn't working for you. I changed a few methods and functions for others but kept your logic intact.

```
=IF(AND(C53=D53, C53="STI"), "No OR, Straight to IM",
   IF(COUNTBLANK(C53:D53)=2, "No Date Input",
   IF(AND(C53 = "Still Pending", D53>=DATE(2013, 1, 1)), "Error, Check Again",
   IF(AND(C53>=DATE(2013, 1, 1), D53 = "Still Pending"), TODAY()-C53,
   IF(COUNT(C53:D53)=2, D53-C53, "not covered")))))
```

You can keep linefeeds in a formula to help organize it. Results as follows:

[image: IF_IF_IF_D53]

Comment: @IanLee -  fwiw, I strongly suspect that your **Still Pending** has a leading and/or trailing space(s), two or more spaces in the middle or a `CHAR(160)` non-breaking space(s) in the middle. IOW, it's malformed data not your formula that is the problem.